# Issues with google-maps-react during deploy on google cloud app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-maps-react

```
Updating service [scanq-client]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 4e807140-c71f-46fe-bfb8-96ca6eed2961 status: FAILURE
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @ant-design/icons@4.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/icons
npm ERR!     @ant-design/icons@"^4.7.0" from antd@4.18.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/antd
npm ERR!   71 more (@ant-design/react-slick, @emotion/react, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/google-maps-react
npm ERR!   google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/google-maps-react
npm ERR!     google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-08-12T02_39_12_791Z-debug-0.log
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=asia-southeast2/4e807140-c71f-46fe-bfb8-96ca6eed2961?project=129289860315
```

Comment: Do you follow any documentation and can you provide any reproducible code?